# Trying to move data from one Azure Blob Storage to another using a Python script

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-factory

I have data that exists in a zipped format in container A that I need to transform using a Python script and am trying to schedule this to occur within Azure, but when writing the output to a new storage container (container B), it simply outputs a csv with the name of the file inside rather than the data.

I've followed the tutorial given on the microsoft site exactly, but I can't get it to work - what am I missing?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/tutorial-run-python-batch-azure-data-factory

```
file_n='iris.csv'

# Load iris dataset from the task node
df = pd.read_csv(file_n)

# Subset records
df = df[df['Species'] == "setosa"]

# Save the subset of the iris dataframe locally in task node
df.to_csv("iris_setosa.csv", index = False, encoding="utf-8")

# Upload iris dataset
blobService.create_blob_from_text(containerName, "iris_setosa.csv", "iris_setosa.csv")
```

Specifically, the final line seems to be just giving me the output of a csv called "iris_setosa.csv" with a contents of "iris_setosa.csv" in cell A1 rather than the actual data that it reads in.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

replace `create_blob_from_text` with `create_blob_from_path`.

`create_blob_from_text` creates a new blob from str/unicode, or updates the content of an existing blob. So you will find text *iris_setosa.csv* in the content of the new blob.

`create_blob_from_path` creates a new blob from a file path, or updates the content of an existing blob. It is what you want.

---

This workaround uses `copy_blob` and `delete_blob` to **move** Azure Blob from one container to another.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobService

def copy_azure_files(self):

        blob_service = BlobService(account_name='account_name', account_key='account_key')
        blob_name = 'iris_setosa.csv'
        copy_from_container = 'test-container'
        copy_to_container = 'demo-container'

        blob_url = blob_service.make_blob_url(copy_from_container, blob_name)
        # blob_url:https://demostorage.blob.core.windows.net/test-container/iris_setosa.csv

        blob_service.copy_blob(copy_to_container, blob_name, blob_url)

        #for move the file use this line
        blob_service.delete_blob(copy_from_container, blob_name)
```

Comment: Thanks Pamela - this looks like it will solve the problem of moving blobs around, but wont allow me to transform the data between the moves. Is that correct?

Comment: @Phishypenguin It moves the whole file, including the data in the file.

Comment: @Phishypenguin Please try my update. It works fine.